# NHibernate bulk restore of backup seems impossible

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to perform a restore of data using NHibernate but I am getting all sorts of errors, from foreign key violations to primary key violations and everything in between.

To give some background, I created a "Base" class from which every class in my application inherits (please don't comment on this, this is what i need/want).
So to perform a backup, i simply call `session.QueryOver<BaseClass>().List<BaseClass>()` and I get all the data, serialize it to javascript, zip it and save it. That's how I create backups.
Now the restore....

I deserialize the backup with ease, get the right types and everything.

I've tried using `session.save(item, item.Id)`, to put the items back with the same ID's as in the original database, but NHibernate doesn't seem to like this, especially when I have foreign keys between tables (or classes).

Browsing the internet, it seems my answers would lie with stateless sessions. I tried these, but I still get all sorts of errors.

One thing i tried was to wrap all the inserts in a try-catch, and retry until i no longer get errors. This sort of worked, but when i call `session.Commit` I get an error message with a lot of **'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint'** messages. I have wrapped all of my inserts into 1 transaction (while writing this I am thinking to try take out the transaction).... Without the transaction it seems to have saved **some** of the data. I think I should have a transaction, as I want to be able to guarantee all or none of the data was restored, to make restores more reliable.

Using try-catch doesn't seem reliable, also it means I have to guess howmany times to retry the insert action on failed items.

One important note I want to add is that when my code is running, I know nothing about the classes or types other than they are of type BaseClass, with an Id field. So one class that is giving an error is a **Menu** class. It has a property which is `List<Menu>`-childMenus and another property of type `Menu`-parentMenu. These 2 properties are mapped using fluent nhibernate to be `HasMany` and `References`, this is how I believe these should be mapped. This is the sort of class that is causing problems for me, because NHibernate has created foreign keys. This is good in my opinion, except that now I can't do a restore easily.

If I don't get a suitable answer or figure this out soon, my solution will be to try and order the items to be restored in such a way that any item which "looks" like it might have a parent object (property of type BaseClass) with a foreign key, i will sort those items into a list and insert them last, and hopefully avoid foreign key constraint violations.

But I am hoping there are other alternatives.

Also, when I do the restore, the Id generator is set to assigned, so I don't think my problem has to do with unknown or invalid id's. In the original data my id's are GUID's. (I may change this to hilo integers later on, but one problem at a time).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Unless I figure out a better alternative, my solution will involve brute forcing the data into the database, using code similar to the following:

```
            var existingCount = 0l;
            var lastCount = -1l;
            while (existingCount < items.Count)
            {
                using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
                {
                    existingCount = session.CreateCriteria<BaseClass>()
                                           .SetProjection(Projections.RowCountInt64())
                                           .List<long>()
                                           .Sum();
                    session.Flush();
                }

                if (existingCount == items.Count)
                {
                    break; // success
                }

                if (lastCount == existingCount)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error restoring backup, no change after retrying inserting new items.");
                }
                lastCount = existingCount;

                try
                {
                    using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
                    {
                        var existingItems = session.QueryOver<BaseClass>().List<BaseClass>().ToList();
                        SaveItemsToDb(existingItems, items, session); // checks if item already exists, if not, tries to save it. Also has some try-catch processing

                        session.Flush();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    //Do nothing, just try again.
                }
            }
```